# Adding password history and password complexity to Linux PAM library

Tags: linux, pam

I am upgrading to Linux PAM version 1.5.3 from version 1.1.4 and would like to get more details on adding password history and password complexity to the Linux PAM library.

Previously I used cracklib but that is no longer supported in version 1.5 and I want to replace it with pam_pwquality.

I think pam_pwquality is fairly straightforward and I found the tarball here:

https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/libpwquality.html

However this also has a dependency on cracklib which Linux PAM itself no longer supports.

When it comes to password history I ran into more problems. My questions are as follows:

password complexity - I need to add pam_pwquality standalone library. Is it's dependency on cracklib only to support dictionary lookups? E.g., if I don't use dictionary I can disable that with "--disable-cracklib-check" and then I wouldn't need to even build cracklib. Is this correct?

password history - Linux PAM itself has a pam_pwhistory subidrectory and creates a shared object for it. I cannot find a separate pwhistory module anywhere. Is this functionality self contained in Linux PAM itself? If it requires a separate library what link can I use to download the tarball?

Thanks

Still in process. Have multiple patch files against Linux PAM version 1.1.4 which need to be repatched in order to build the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

1. It [looks like](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Alibpwquality%2Flibpwquality%20cracklib&type=code) pwquality only needs the libcrack libraries if you want to use the libcrack dictionaries, but you might have to ask the `pam_pwquality` developers for anything more specific
2. Yes, the pam history module (`/usr/lib/security/pam_pwhistory.so`) is provided by the base Linux PAM itself, so should be downloadable as part of https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/linux-pam.html

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the pam_pwhistory. I was just trying to make sure because before cracklib was deprecated there was a pw_cracklib module in Linux PAM itself BUT you also needed to build and install the standalone cracklib library.